# A question regarding sizing some resistors in a circuit

Tags: resistors, bjt, zener, npn

I have the following circuit's old version soldered which works fine in real. The updated circuit in the below diagram exists only in simulation. Recently I will in real add a zener with a series resistor and a Schottky to the positive rail for reverse polarity protection as you can see in the below schematic. And mainly I will add  a new output Vout2.

The reason for the zener is I want to limit the Vout1 voltage to around 8V if the supply rail exceeds 8V. The supply rail Vcc can be between from 5V upto 24V.

I want the circuit to have two outputs Vout1 and Vout2. Vout1 will be an Low-High pulse train with 0-5V or 0-8V amplitude(low can be between zero and one volt).

[image]

I want Vout2 to swing between around 0V(or a bit more) to around 15V. Vx and Rx is known which are 15V and 2.1k.

But for a good saturation I couldnt figure out an optimum value for Rb since Vout can be from 5V to 8V as I explained.

In simulation I get what I want to see, but I'm not sure about the values for Rz and the base resistor Rb. What should be a good value for Rx and Rb and how do you conclude that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For robust saturation, over temperature and environmental degradation (including nuclear fluxes), assume the beta degrades by 90%. Assume beta becomes TEN. That means 15v/2.1K / 10 = 0.7mA into base.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I remember saturation beta was around ten.  For robust saturation if I set Rb properly for 5V Vcc at 12V, the Rb will be hopeless at 12V Vcc I guess. Should that 0.7mA be the minimum I need to set, if I overshoot like 1mA for example is that still alright?    Is Rz fine?

Comment: Go for minimum of 0.7mA. Its safe to go to 10mA or 50mA base current. Examine the datasheet for any Ibase limits.